# How to embed external urls in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to embed an external url inside my angular app using iframe.
This is what I'm getting.

[image: How to embed external urls in angular?]

and the error says that:

[image]

Following is the template in which I'm trying to embed an external url

```
<iframe height="500" width="100%" [src]="url | safe" frameborder="0"></iframe>

//   url = `https://fonts.google.com/`;

// this is a dummy url. this url will be replaced by a page on my another website (owned by myself but different domain)
```

Following is the pipe used to bypass security risk:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'safe',
})
export class SafePipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}
  transform(url): SafeResourceUrl {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);
  }
}
```

And still I'm getting the following error & the external webpage is not getting embedded.

```
Refused to display 'https://fonts.google.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.
```

**Note I'm using latest version of angular**

The above method is something I found online. I couldn't find anything else. Can someone suggest a best approach to embed external urls as an `iframe`.

Answer (score 0):

This error means that the site you are trying to embed, https://fonts.google.com/, doesn't allow sites with a different domain name to embed it. There is no way to bypass, you can read more about this on [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options)

> if you specify SAMEORIGIN, you can still use the page in a frame as
> long as the site including it in a frame is the same as the one
> serving the page.

Comment: So which means I can embed my own domains .. right?

Comment: yes, if your domain will return the SAMEORIGIN value for x-frame-options, you can read more about content-security-policy - you can also limit specific types of content (like scripts, styles, etc)

Comment: @mex You can use JSONP to avoid that kind of errors. Take a look at my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [JSONP approach](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_jsonp.asp#:%7E:text=JSONP%20stands%20for%20JSON%20with,instead%20of%20the%20XMLHttpRequest%20object.) to avoid the CORS issues:

HTML:

```html
<iframe #iframe type="text/javascript" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

TS:

```
src: string; // <- YOUR URL
@ViewChild('iframe') iframe: ElementRef;

 ngAfterViewInit() {
   const doc = this.iframe.nativeElement.contentDocument || this.iframe.nativeElement.contentElement.contentWindow;
   const content = `
       <html>
       <head>
         <base target="_parent">
       </head>
       <body>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="${this.src}"></script>
       </body>
     </html>
   `;

   doc.open();
   doc.write(content);
   doc.close();
 }
```